# I have a column containing list of dictionaries - type of column - Series

Tags: python, pandas

[image]How do I retrieve all data from within this column to separate columns? SChema: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

```
                                                    hits hits
0      [{'hitNumber': '1', 'time': '0', 'hour': '1'    1
1      [{'hitNumber': '1', 'time': '0', 'hour': '0'    1
2      [{'hitNumber': '1', 'time': '0', 'hour': '16'   1
3      [{'hitNumber': '1', 'time': '0', 'hour': '4'    1
4      [{'hitNumber': '1', 'time': '0', 'hour': '11'   1
```

Like a separate column for 'hitNumber', 'hour' etc
Type for the column - <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: What are the column names?

Comment: I want to have the column names like - hitNumber, time, hour etc. SChema : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Comment: I was asking about the current column names as it appears from the image you posted you have 2 columns named 'hit'.

Comment: why is the dictionary within a `list` if it's just 1 value in each row?